# SharedPreferences commit method showing deprecated inside flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using below code to save the values at sharedPreferences

```
_onChanged(bool value) async {
  sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    checkValue = value;
    sharedPreferences.setBool("check", checkValue);
    sharedPreferences.setString("username", username.text);
    sharedPreferences.setString("password", password.text);
    sharedPreferences.commit();
    getCredential();
  });
}
```

But while using I found that commit method is deprecated, So what will be the replacement for it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to use `commit()` anymore since every set (`setString`, `setBool`, etc.) executes a commit already.

On iOS, synchronize is deprecated (this is what `commit()` does on iOS to persist the values), so `commit()` wasn't needed anymore.

On Android, executing a commit on every set has always been the default behaviour, so `commit()` is redundant on Android.

In summary, just invoking the set methods should be fine for both Android and iOS.

Source: [SharedPreferences' API documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/commit.html)